# Create an array within a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to design a function within a function that takes n number of inputs? Is an array needed? The idea is the remove the input upper bound. Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT find_me('APPLE',
               colors('red', 'green', 'yellow',n),
               locations('USA', 'Central America', 'South America',n))
  FROM dual;
```

So the example above has the function *colors* which takes 3 inputs. But it should easily take 10, or even 83. Same with the locations function. How would you go about this?

A basic example of what I have currently is -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_me(TYPE        varchar2,
                                   COLOR_1     varchar2,
                                   COLOR_2     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_3     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_4     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_5     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_6     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_7     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_8     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_9     varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   COLOR_10    varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_1  varchar2,
                                   LOCATION_2  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_3  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_4  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_5  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_6  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_7  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_8  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_9  varchar2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                   LOCATION_10 varchar2 DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURN varchar2 IS
BEGIN
  IF TYPE = 'APPLE' AND COLOR_1 = 'RED' THEN
    RETURN LOCATION_1;
  ELSIF TYPE = 'APPLE' AND COLOR_1 = 'YELLOW' THEN
    RETURN LOCATION_2;
  ELSE
    RETURN 'UNKNOWN';
  END IF;
END;

SELECT find_me('APPLE', 'RED', 'USA') FROM dual; -- RESULT 'USA'
```

So in short, I want to take COLOR_1-10 and LOCATION_1-10 and allow n number of inputs.

Comment: The logic behind the function FIND_ME - locates what country fruits are in using color and location. Pretty much a big case statement. In the function, I have specified 10 colors and 10 locations, but if there is a way to clean that up and remove the upper bound that would be ideal. Like maybe I don't need the inner functions COLORS and LOCATIONS if there is a way to remove the upper bound of inputs.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Is `find_me` using the passed-in values to look up from a table? What are the other functions actually doing? A collection is probably still the way to go but without seeing how you're currently using these things I can't tell you how to change.

Comment: Okay, I added an example of what I currently have. find_me uses passed in values and checks them against logic within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure your example really makes sense, but an equivalent using [built-in collection types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/addci/extensibility-constants-types-and-mappings.html#GUID-7DA22716-DAF2-4B1B-831B-4766082578C4):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_me(
  TYPE varchar2,
  COLORS sys.odcivarchar2list,
  LOCATIONS sys.odcivarchar2list
)
RETURN varchar2 IS
BEGIN
  IF TYPE = 'APPLE' AND COLORS(1) = 'RED' THEN
    RETURN COALESCE(LOCATIONS(1),LOCATIONS(2));
  END IF;
END;
/

SELECT find_me(
    'APPLE',
    sys.odcivarchar2list('RED', 'GREEN', 'YELLOW'),
    sys.odcivarchar2list('USA', 'Central America', 'South America')
  ) as result
FROM dual;

RESULT                        
------------------------------
USA
```

You could define your own types if you prefer of course. And you need to check you don't try to look at a null collection or elements that don't exist - for example that code would get "ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count" if the locations argument was passed as `sys.odcivarchar2list(null)`, because there is no element 2.

Read more about collections [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7115C8B6-62F9-496D-BEC3-F7441DFE148A).

---

Or with your edited example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_me(
  TYPE varchar2,
  COLORS sys.odcivarchar2list,
  LOCATIONS sys.odcivarchar2list
)
RETURN varchar2 IS
BEGIN
  IF TYPE = 'APPLE' AND COLORS(1) = 'RED' THEN
    RETURN LOCATIONS(1);
  ELSIF TYPE = 'APPLE' AND COLORS(1) = 'YELLOW' THEN
    RETURN LOCATIONS(2);
  ELSE
    RETURN 'UNKNOWN';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

```
SELECT find_me(
    'APPLE',
    sys.odcivarchar2list('RED', 'GREEN', 'YELLOW'),
    sys.odcivarchar2list('USA', 'Central America', 'South America')
  ) as result
FROM dual;

RESULT                        
------------------------------
USA

SELECT find_me(
    'APPLE',
    sys.odcivarchar2list('YELLOW', 'BLUE'),
    sys.odcivarchar2list('USA', 'Central America', 'South America')
  ) as result
FROM dual;

RESULT                        
------------------------------
Central America
```

You could also use a case statement:

```
...
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN TYPE = 'APPLE' AND COLORS(1) = 'RED' THEN
      RETURN LOCATIONS(1);
    WHEN TYPE = 'APPLE' AND COLORS(1) = 'YELLOW' THEN
      RETURN LOCATIONS(2);
    ELSE
      RETURN 'UNKNOWN';
  END CASE;
END;
/
```

Comment: Oh, this is very cool, I haven't seen sys.odcivarchar2list before. Let me try this out, and sorry if the example wasn't very clear. But I think you might have answered my question!

Comment: That's just a built-in varray type, which is handy; you could define your own, either at schema level or - if you're only going to use it in PL/SQL - maybe as a package type, and put this and any other related functions in a package.